# Cannot Connect to Redshift using federated ADFS and IAM via psycopg2

Tags: sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, pg8000

For user access to Redshift, we are using federated security between ADFS and IAM. We are able to successfully connect and interact with Redshift via dBeaver and other tools using a JDBC connection string, as well as with Python using a user on the database - not a federated user. However psycopg2, pg8000, and sqlalchemy fail due to the additional connection options required for this model.

Our connection string:

```
    jdbc:redshift:iam://{host}:{port}/{database}?plugin_name=com.amazon.redshift.plugin.AdfsCredentialsProvider&preferred_role=arn:aws:iam::{RoleID}:role/{Group}&idp_host=sts.{Domain}.com&idp_port=443&autocreate=true&user={Domain}\username&password={Password}
```

psycopg2, pg8000, and sqlalchemy all fail with some version of the below

```
invalid connection option "plugin_name"
```

or

```
Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'redshift+psycopg2:iam://
```

Presumably, because of the Redshift and AWS specific options and IAM protocol.

The only solution that works is using JayDeBeAPI, as it will take a raw JDBC connection string - no matter how specialized. This issue with this is that JayDeBeAPI is significantly slower than the other libraries - e.g. 26 seconds for a 70k row query vs 1.2 in psycopg2.

Is there any possible way to pass arbitrary connection options to psycopg2 or pg8000? Or any other Python libraries that will accomplish this?